# Type hinting a dataclass for instance variable that accepts multiple types as an argument and stores single type

Tags: python, python-typing, python-dataclasses

I want my class constructor to accept variable inputs, then normalize them for storage and access. For example:

```py
class Ticket:
    def __init__(self, number: int | str):
        self.number: int = int(number)

# so that it's flexible in creation:
t = Ticket(6)
t = Ticket('7')

# but consistent when accessed:
isinstance(t.number, int)  # True
```

I don't know the right OOP term, but I want to make sure my class's interface? signature? correctly reflects that it will accept `.number` as int or string, but accessing `.number` will always give an int.

The above works (though I'm open to suggestions), but attempting to do the equivalent with a dataclass gives a type error in Pylance:

```py
@dataclass
class Ticket:
    number: int | str
   #^^^^^^ Pylance: Declaration "number" is obscured by a declaration of the same name

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.number: int = int(self.number)
```

Is this fixable in the dataclass version? Or just a limit of dataclasses? I'd like to keep the other benefits of dataclass if possible.

Comment: I think that's what your code does. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: You're already pretty close to a good solution. What exactly do you expect your code or your IDE to do that it currently doesn't, based on the code you shared? The type hint in the function's signature (i.e. `: int | str`) is doing what you need. And the type of `.number` can also be derived. (note that passing an `int` to a function that expects a `float` would not cause a warning in Python, as an example - please provide an example of something that you would expect to cause a warning or error, that doesn't)

Comment: BTW, it's preferable to use `isinstance(t.number, int)` instead of `type(t.number) is int`

Comment: Be flexible by adding a class method that takes a string, so you create an instance with either `Ticket(6)` or with `Ticket.from_string('7')`. Then `__init__` *always* takes an `int` as its argument, and the caller is responsible for knowing how to create a `Ticket` given the information they can provide.

Comment: @Barmar Fair. Mostly because I'm new to these concepts and type hint syntax, and didn't think I'd have guessed it right.
Also because a dataclass variation of this (now added to Q) is marked by Pylance as a type error.

Comment: The existing code is broken (`number` isn't in scope in `__post_init__`). I assume you meant `self.number: int = int(self.number)`. No idea if that will satisfy PyLance, I suspect it won't, but at least it would actually work at runtime.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Good catch, fixed. Yes, it runs, no Pylance doesn't like it.

Comment: @Barmar and Jacktose: If the question focuses on the PyLance issues with dataclasses, that *is* an answerable question. The original, non-`dataclass` class works fine, but you need some massaging for the `dataclass` case (I have an answer for it, but the question closed seconds before I could post it).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks. I rewrote it to focus on the dataclass part. Hopefully that's enough to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a super-pretty way to do this; the class level annotation and the `__post_init__` level annotation of the same thing are in conflict, so the only way to handle it in a way static analysis will accept is to make them different things. You can do this by:

1. Making a separately annotated field that is an `InitVar`, something provided for initialization, but that is not an attribute of the object
2. Making the attribute field explicitly `init=False` so it's *not* accepted for initialization but *is* an attribute

Together, you end up with something like this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, InitVar

@dataclass
class Ticket:
    number: int = field(init=False)  # The actual attribute; not accepted by generated __init__
                                     # as an argument, only an int
    numinit: InitVar[int | str]  # The argument, that's not an attribute, and can be int or str

    def __post_init__(self, numinit):  # InitVar fields are passed to __post_init__
        self.number = int(numinit)     # And we can use them to initialize the uninitialized
```

This isn't perfect; the names *have* to differ (the initializing argument can't also be named `number`, at least not without some horrible hackery that would be much worse than simply writing your own `__init__` in the first place). If the name needs to match, you can just write your own `__init__`. Sure it's annoying that `dataclass` won't do it for you, but you'll still get all the *other* generated code (e.g. `__repr__`, `__eq__`), so it's not terrible for simple cases like this (it's rather simpler than `InitVar`, though if you had many attributes, and just one `InitVar` needed, `InitVar` starts to look better).

```
@dataclass
class Ticket:
    number: int

    def __init__(self, number: int | str):  # Accept as union type
        self.number = int(number)           # Convert to single type
```

As chepner notes in the comments, this design (accepting non-uniform types, and coercing to a common type) is generally frowned upon; `int` is special, but most classes should accept uniform types, and leave it up to users to perform any necessary data conversions. It's frankly a little misleading to say they're equally valid types; you don't really accept all strings, just ones that *happen* to look exactly like integers.

If you do want to allow construction by multiple means, a reasonable way to do this is with the normal constructor taking `int` alone, and an `@classmethod` alternate constructor for accepting strings (much like `int` has `int.from_bytes` for constructing from a `bytes` object):

```
from typing import Self

@dataclass
class Ticket:
    number: int

    @classmethod
    def from_str(cls, number: str) -> Self:  # Accept as string, returns instance of cls via Self annotation
        return cls(int(number))              # Convert and invoke regular construction
```

which means you can't accept *mixed* `int` and `str` data and call via a uniform entry point (without manually `int`-ifying yourself), but any given data source is usually one or the other, and can choose the appropriate interface (`Ticket(someint)` or `Ticket.from_str(somestr)`).

But even here that's probably going overboard; just accept `int` uniformly, and leave it to the callers to convert before calling if needed.

Comment: Wow, that's a great explanation, thank you!
I guess the real, real answer is to adjust my priorities: consistency and explicitness are more important than Postel's Law.

Comment: @Jacktose: Especially when Postel's Law isn't particularly relevant thanks to static typing telling you ahead of time whether or not an input will be valid. Types are easy, it's values that are hard, and with an `int`-only design, values aren't hard either (all `int`s are legal here, but not all `str` would be). Postel's Law is more important for "fuzzy" interfaces where things degrade to strings and/or raw bytes (network connections, pipes between processes) than it is for simple function prototypes.

Comment: Yeah, this is all stuff under my control, and I was really just being lazy, not deciding whether I was going to convert types in my input-from-file function or in my object constructor.